# WampServer is not working

Tags: wampserver

I have just installed WampServer. But it's icon is always red. I restarted my pc but it is still red. What should I do about it?
I already changed  httpd.conf in c:/wamp/bim/apache/apache/conf.
I changed listen 80 to listen 8080 but nothing changed.
I also closed Windows Firewall and Skype has not been started.

Comment: your skype is not working also ?

Comment: @Ronak I mean, I have not started it, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, :-
Go to skype:

> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use
>   port 80 and 443 as alternative".

restart wamp,
Hope this helps..

Comment: check this, 
http://www.ttkalec.com/blog/resolving-yellow-wamp-server-status-freeing-up-port-80-for-apache/

Answer (score 1):

If the Wampmanager icon stays red then both the APache and MySQL services have failed to start, so something sounds very wrong.

Have a look at the Windows Event Viewer, in the section called Microsoft -> Applications

Look for messages from MYSQL and Apache. If they fail before they can write to there error logs they log error messages in there. Thay should give you an idea about what is wrong.